# Cannot find a way to make counter-increment work (Chrome/Firefox)

Tags: html, css, pagination

Here is a piece of HTML/CSS code, which should print, thanks to CSS' counters, the page number in footer when printed :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        counter-reset: page;
      }
      div.footer {
        display: table-footer-group;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0pt;
        right: 0pt;
      }
      div.footer:after {
        counter-increment: page;
        content: "Page " counter(page);
      }
      p {
        page-break-after: always;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="footer"></div>
    <p>Hello world page 1</p>
    <p>Hello world page 2</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The fact is, with Firefox 79.0, I get "Page 1" on first page, and "Page" on second. With Chrome 84.0, I get "Page 1" on both pages.

I tried to use @page at-rule, native "page" counter (as described on [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/)), I still can't find what I'm missing.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: i'm afrais it's a known bug .... You may check on similar question here on SO to find out .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681472/css-counter-increment-page-on-print-view-issue (among other Q/A )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve what you're trying to. The reason you get "Page 1" is because you're incrementing the counter inside the `div.footer:after` declaration, which appears only once in your HTML code.

The CSS counter, when it's read, is calculated based on that element's location in the document, like described in the specs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

So in your case, you can think about it like this:

```css
div.footer:after {
  content: "Page " counter(page); /* when displayed, read the value of `page` */
}
p {
  counter-increment: page; /* counter increments with every occurrence of a <p> tag */
}
```

and

```html
<div class="footer"></div> <!-- `page` counter is always 0, as no occurrences of a <p> tag yet -->
<p>Hello world page 1</p> <!-- sets counter to 1 -->
<p>Hello world page 2</p> <!-- sets counter to 2 -->
```

or

```html
<p>Hello world page 1</p> <!-- sets counter to 1 -->
<div class="footer"></div> <!-- `page` counter is always 1, as there was a single occurrence of a <p> tag -->
<p>Hello world page 2</p> <!-- sets counter to 2 -->
```

or

```html
<p>Hello world page 1</p> <!-- sets counter to 1 -->
<p>Hello world page 2</p> <!-- sets counter to 2 -->
<div class="footer"></div> <!-- `page` counter is always 2, as there were two occurrences of a <p> tag -->
```

Comment: What you probably want to do is have a `<div class="footer">` on every "page" block, which will correctly display the counter for each individual page.